# Fieldsets with django-form-designer

Tags: django-cms

I'm using [django-form-designer](https://github.com/philomat/django-form-designer) for django-cms to allow admin users to create forms through the admin UI.

For long forms, I'd like to be able to organize the fields into fieldsets, so that when the formis rendered there's a box around related fields. Is it possible to organize form fields into fieldsets using django-form-designer and the admin UI?

Answer (score 0):

According to the maintainer, [fieldsets are not yet supported](https://github.com/philomat/django-form-designer/issues/45).